# Sign In With Linkedin in localhost won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, linkedin-api

```js
api_key: 8193cva9nkxnua
authorize: true
```

I got this error in my browser console: "Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration."

just because I can't register my localhost domain to Authorized Redirect URLs: found in: https://www.linkedin.com/developer/ . It is invalid. How can I test Sign In to linkedin within my localhost? Is this possible? or i need a registered domain? I only use xampp. My API key is only a sample. I keep the original. Thanks.

Comment: For localhost , you can create a virtualhost at the place of localhost , and then use that virtualhost domain instead of localhost, it will work in this way.

Comment: @Arsh thanks very much. i will try.